# Import fbx model eyes are wrong

Tags: modeling, import, .fbx

I need some help. I am trying import an fbx model into blender. But the problem is that its eyes are all wrong.

[image]

The Backface culling is already turned off. So that isn't the problem and I have tried to switch Blend Mode from Alpha blend to opaque. But the texture just turns black. Here is a link to the blend file. https://mega.nz/file/tDd1VaRS#4rCZTiyLvyzLeZX2b_AumYif0mD7b_gbtgwlUyMkTxk

[image]